# When I pass a character array in java then the array passed is different.For example if I pass an array aqdf the passed array is actually aqqq

Tags: java, arrays, pass-by-reference

I am trying to implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters without using any additional datastrutures.
Here is my code:

```
package CTCI;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrStrng1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of characters in the string?");
        int l=s.nextInt();
        char[] ca=new char[l];
        System.out.println("Enter the characters in the string?");
        for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
        {
            char c=s.next().charAt(0);  
            ca[i]=c;

        }

        if(unique(ca,l))
            System.out.println("YES");
        else
            System.out.println("NO");
      s.close();    

    }

    public static boolean unique(char[] str,int l)
    {
        //using insertion sort to sort the character array
        char c;
        for(int i=1;i<l;i++)
        {
             c=str[i];
             int j=i;
             while(j>0 && c<str[j-1])
             {
                 str[j]=str[j-1];
                 j--;

             }


        }
        //Now checking if any two consecutive characters are same
        for(int j=0;j<l-1;j++)
        {
            if(str[j]==str[j+1])
                return false;
        }
        return true;//If no two consecutive characters are same then the character array is unique
    }

}
```

This solution is not working since the passed character array to the function unique gets modified e.g. abcd becomes abbb.
Am I missing out on something?What is the bug in my code?
Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: The only place where you change things in the array is in the sort.  Put the code in a debugger, and find where in there your code is assigning a value you don't expect.  All I see, with as much time as I'm willing to spend on it, is that you assign a character to 'c' but don't put it back in the array anywhere.

Comment: Try printing the contents of str in the inner loop and try to understand the behaviour of your program.

Comment: I have used the debugger and found that the array char[] ca is input properly but when it is passed to the function unique(char[] str,int l) it gets modified.

Comment: so debug it within unique -- let us know what you have attempted that you don't understand.  Don't ask us to debug it for you.

Comment: I don't understand why the character array is being modified when passed to the function unique?

Comment: What do you mean "when it is passed?"  Does it have a different value at the beginning of unique than it does when unique is called with it?

Comment: It has a different value in the main function but when the character array is passed to unique it changes.For Example in main it has the correct input value of abcd but when I check its value in unique it shows abbb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem with your insertion sort, you forgot to insert the value of c in smaller index(j-1). Hence the correct soring is:

```
    char c;  
    for(int i=1;i<l;i++)
    {
         c=str[i];
         int j=i;
         while(j>0 && c<str[j-1])
         {                 
             str[j]=str[j-1];
             str[j-1]=c;
             --j;
         }
    }
```

Rest is fine.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you wish to implement the insertion sort yourself.
because java has sort which you can use on Arrays.
any way the issue is in the insertion sort implementation you forgot to switch between the numbers and you just assign the bigger character try this:

```
 char c;
        char tmp;
        for(int i=1;i<l;i++)
        {
             c=str[i];
             int j=i;
             while(j>0 && c<str[j-1])
             {
                 tmp = str[j];
                 str[j]=str[j-1];
                 str[j-1] = tmp;
                 j--;

             }


        }
//      Arrays.sort(str);
        //Now checking if any two consecutive characters are same
```

on another note I suggest giving meaningful names to your variables ( even in these tutorials ) it really helps in the future.

hope it helps.